# Repeatably Feeding Input to a Process' Standard Input

Tags: c#, .net, io-redirection

I have a (C#) console application which maintains a state. The state can be altered by feeding the application with various input through the console. I need to be able to both feed the application with a bit of input, then read the output rinse and repeat.

I create a new process and do all of the normal work of redirecting the input/output. The problem is that after I've sent input and call `ReadLine()` on the standard output it does not return a value before I call `Close()` on the standard input after which I cannot write anymore to the input stream.

How can I keep open the input stream while still receiving output?

```
 var process = new Process
                          {
                              StartInfo =
                                  {
                                      FileName =
                                          @"blabal.exe",
                                      RedirectStandardInput = true,
                                      RedirectStandardError = true,
                                      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                      UseShellExecute = false,
                                      CreateNoWindow = true,
                                      ErrorDialog = false
                                  }
                          };


        process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        process.Start();

        var standardInput = process.StandardInput;
        standardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        var standardOutput = process.StandardOutput;
        var standardError = process.StandardError;

        standardInput.Write("ready");
        standardInput.Close(); // <-- output doesn't arrive before after this line
        var outputData = standardOutput.ReadLine();

        process.Close();
        process.Dispose();
```

The console application I'm redirecting IO from is very simple. It reads from the console using `Console.Read()` and writes to it using `Console.Write()`. I know for certain that this data is readable, since I have another application that reads from it using standard output / input (not written in .NET).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because of you are using `Write("ready")` which is will append a string to the text, instead use `WriteLine("ready")`. that simple :).

Comment: Noway! God, you are correct. What if I needed to write something that wasn't prepended with \r\n? Like prepending it linux style with a single '\n'.

Comment: @Qua: Use `Environment.NewLine` instead, `A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.` check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Comment: WriteLine will automatically use Enviroment.Newline then?